# convert arrayof characters to string

Tags: c, string, char

I am writing code in c language.

1. `char a[]={p,r,a,d,e,e,p}`
   I want to add `'0/'` at the end to make it string.
   Or is there any method to make it string other than adding null at the end?
2. `char *a=pradeep;`
   Convert this to string by adding null at the end

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the size of the array `a` so you cannot add a null terminator to it. You could change the declaration to:

```
char a[] = "pradeep";
```

which will implicitly add the null terminator. Or:

```
char a[] = { 'p', 'r', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'p', 0 };
```

but the string literal is simpler and clearer. Most, if not all, of the C string library functions require a null terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *a="pradeep";
```

makes a string literal and adds the null character at the end.

If you really want to declare it using a syntax similar to your 1, you may do this :

```
char a[] = {'p','r','a','d','e','e','p', 0};
```

but there is no reason to do this.

**EDIT Regarding the question in comment**

If you want to create a string from `n` characters you receive, you may do this :

```
char *a = malloc(n*sizeof(char)+1);
```

If it's always 10 chars or less, you may declare it as

```
char a[11];
```

Then set each `a[i]` with the received value, and the last one with `0`.

You could also use sprintf to do the concatenation but in any case you must ensure you have enough place allocated.

Comment: Actually there is one special case when you might need the latter. When you have a peculiar extension to normal 7-bit ASCII, you cannot trust the font in the source code editor to have the same "extended ASCII" value as the application. I have encountered this several times when implementing symbol tables for embedded displays. The solution is to type out the ASCII number instead of the symbol. With your former notation you can only do so by adding hex values. ->

Comment: Suppose we want to add the character with hex value 0xAA to the string. If we'd write "pr\xAAadeep" we would get a bug, because a hex sequence inside a C string literal can only be terminated by a non-hex digit. And in this case the compiler would treat AAadee as valid hex. So your latter example with character-by-character is safer and less confusing.

Comment: @dystroy, I AM receiving series of characters, take it as 10 number  of characters from rs232. the received in a variable are in the form of characters or a group of characters. I want to make them string.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make any sense, and won't compile.

String literals are best written using string literal syntax:

```
const char *a = "pradeep";
```

This will include the terminating character, making `a` point at a C string that you can use with any of the string-processing functions, print out, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
1). char a[]={'p','r','a','d','e','e','p','\0'};
```

Now its an array containing a valid string.

```
2). char *a="pradeep";
```

This automatically appends null at end to make valid string.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a literal string to a character array, the compiler will automatically create the correct array with the terminating `'\0'` character at the end:

```
char a[] = "pradeep";
```

The above is the same as writing

```
char a[] = { 'p', 'r', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'p', '\0' };
```

Also, using arrays is the recommended way, but the first alternative above is equivalent to

```
char *pa = "pradeep";
```

However, with this last, you can no longer use the `sizeof` operator, as that will return the size of the *pointer* and not the length of the string. Another note about the `sizeof` operator, for the first two examples, it will return the size of the array and not the length of the string, i.e. `sizeof` for a character array will include the terminating character.

Comment: The `char* pa = ..` also makes it non-modifiable, whereas `char a[] = ...;` is modifiable.