# convert group of character to string in c

Tags: c

I AM receiving series of characters, take it as 10 number of characters from rs232. the received in a variable are in the form of characters or a group of characters. I want to make them string

Comment: what you have tried till yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert arrayof characters to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178038/convert-arrayof-characters-to-string)

Answer (score 3):

Remember C does not have strings, but you can have an array of `char`s.

Create an array of chars of the appropriate size (one extra for `\0`).

```
char str[11];
```

Loop over your characters, setting each one to the appropriate value in this char array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    str[i] = your_chars[i];
}
```

Toss the null terminator on the end.

```
str[10] = '\0';
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/UZFyvVup).

[Fasked](https://stackoverflow.com/users/948318/fasked) also points out that this can be achieved with `strncpy()`.

Comment: @KingsIndian Haven't done C for a while, can you please point out the UB? Thanks.

Comment: Last line should be `str[10]=0;`

Comment: @KingsIndian I noticed that and fixed it, but `'\0'` will work too, right?

Comment: @alex you've written `strncpy`

Comment: @fasked That's what I get for not remembering the standard library very well.

Comment: @alex, sorry I can't edit your post (I need to edit at least 6 characters), function's name is `strncpy` not `strncopy`.